# Ansible inventory limit child group to specific group members

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I know it's possible to run a playbook against the first half of `group1`, but is it possible to create child groups like that in the inventory already? This is an example:

```
[group1]
srv1
srv2
srv3
srv4
 
[halfgroup1:child]
group1[0:2] #<-- This should contain srv1 and srv2
```

I can run the playbook against `group1[0:2]`, or against `srv1,srv2`. But is it possible to do these in the inventory already, so i can run the playbook against `halfgroup1`?

With the example above, Ansible is unable to parse the inventory. So I guess it's just not possible, but if anybody has an idea, feel free to share it with me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just taking this upside-down. The following inventory declares 2 "halfgroups" and a parent group joining the two. You can target any of those.

```
[halfgroup1]
srv1
srv2

[halfgroup2]
srv3
srv4

[group1:children]
halfgroup1
halfgroup2
```

Comment: In this case this sounds good, but if i have 4 webservers, 4 loadbalancers and 4 databases i want to sort them into these groups. I could create two groups with two webservers/loadbalancers/databases earch and use halfgroup1 and halfgroup2, but if i want to run a playbook against all webservers only there is no webservers group. I Could add another webservers group to the inventory, but this inventory will be so huge when having 60 servers :D

Comment: I think that what you are really looking for for is [`serial: X`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#setting-the-batch-size-with-serial) where X is half the size of your group. Meanwhild, regarding creating groups and size of inventory, you might want to switch to a custom dynamic inventory that will do that job for you. That being said, I don't consider 60 servers that big to have a dozen groups. Some of my current static inventories have much more than that (groups and servers).